# How to get the id number of an attribute value on Magento list product page?

Tags: php, magento

I'm looking for a snippet to display attribute value id of a product on a products list page,
I already use this piece of code to display attributes values but I need to get their ID number:

```
$attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getAttributeText('icontags');
```

**Example:**

**Attribute:** Color

**Value:** red

**Value Id:** 580

Comment: What does the $_product->getId() return that you have in your code your provided?

Comment: You need to post more code. Add in the HTML you are using. That will help us understand what you need for the attribute id's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you are referring to the option_id, which can simply be got with getData

```
$attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getData('icontags');
```

Comment: I have tried getData function, but like a dumb I was expecting an array, not a string so my other function could not work. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getAttributeText('color');
// will return selected value

// if you want to get option id
$attribute=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute("color");
```

Answer (score -2):

`$_product->getId()` will get you the product id.